# random number for numeric (16,10) datatype

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a requirement to generate a random number (in place of identity), so I tried these approaches, but while inserting data I met with a primary key violation after a while.

**Attempt #1 (old query):**

```
SELECT CONVERT(NUMERIC (14,2), GETDATE()) * rand() 
FROM sometable
```

**Attempt #2 (modified query):**

```
SELECT CONVERT(NUMERIC(14,2), GETDATE()) * RAND(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY)) 
FROM sometable
```

Note:

The first query is always getting duplicate when we have more than one record to insert.

The second query gets duplicated while inserting the bulk records ex: 5000 records per transaction.

*Sample table structure:*

```
CREATE table #test
(
     id numeric(16,10) primary key
)
```

*Query:*

```
INSERT into #test (ID)
   SELECT CONVERT(NUMERIC(14, 2), GETDATE()) * RAND(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY)) 
   FROM sys.objects

SELECT * FROM #test
```

Requirement:

I need to insert any large number of rows without any primary key violations.

Kindly advise - I am open to any other alternate ideas as well.

Thanks in advance..

Please correct me if my question is not clear enough.

Comment: You will never be able to guarantee that any randomly generated number isn't already present in your table. You will have to either check ahead of time, or handle the PK violation.

Comment: Hi Bill.. Is there any alternate could you suggest..

Comment: Why does the requirement preclude using `IDENTITY`? It's meant for this task.

Comment: See also: [Birthday problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem)

Comment: Part of the issue is a misunderstanding in the RAND function. It will return the same value for all rows in any given query. It does NOT return a new random value for each row. select top 5 RAND() from sys.tables

Comment: Hi Sean, you are right if you simply execute rand() itself, but if you are executing with cast of newid() to varbinary inside the rand(), then it will return different values for each row. Try this SELECT TOP 5 RAND(CAST(NEWID() AS [varbinary])) FROM sys.objects

Answer (score 1):

Shrink the problem down.  If you were generating a number from 1 to 10, how long would it take to get a duplicate?  The problem you're facing is no different, except with a larger problem set.

If you're using something as a generated primary key, you should use an identity column or a GUID.  That or a natural key like a SKU or PID or UPC, for example, if you're cataloging products.

Something like this:

```
INSERT into #test (ID)
  SELECT NEWID()
```